# Google Maps APIv2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm writing an app for Android that uses Google maps APIv2.
It works almost on all devices. But there is a problem with Android 4.0.4 and 4.2.2. Application crashes during map initialization.

On Android 4.0.4 it works after reboot, on 4.2.2 it doesn't work.

Here code for initialization:

```
public class MyMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
{
      private GoogleMap map;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);
         // Getting Google Play availability status
         int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

         // Showing status
         if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
         { // Google Play Services are not available
               int requestCode = 10;
               Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
               dialog.show();
         }
         else 
         {// Google Play Services are available
               // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
               SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

               // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
               map = fm.getMap();

               // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
               map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         }
      }   
}
```

activity_my_map.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you cannot determine what the stack trace means, edit your question and paste the stack trace into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that getMap may return null, try to setup your code somewhat like this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // First incarnation of this activity.
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    } else {
        // Reincarnated activity. The obtained map is the same map instance in the previous
        // activity life cycle. There is no need to reinitialize it.
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is from the API demo RetainMapActivity

Comment: `RetainMapActivity` example causes leak of first `Activity` instance, because `GoogleMap` object (or some other object in this object's graph) needs to hold onto the `Context`.

Comment: I do not believe that to cause a leak, as I use that approach and things such as the Fragment Callback pattern extensively and have not experienced leaks. It would become a problem if I handed the whole Activity object without using a WeakReference, otherwise not.

Comment: This is not what you believe in or not. Run your app (or `RetainMapActivity` example), rotate the screen, do a heap dump and view it in [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). You will see two activities.

Comment: In that case, does it then grow further? If not, it is a price I'm willing to pay to enable orientation change without the need to reload the fragment.